# How to convert from timestamp ltz(9) data type to date format dd mm yyyy in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi all is there any way to convert from timestamp ltz as datatype to date format dd/ mm / yyyy  .

Tried using try to timestamp , try todate in snowflake but not working it's throwing error converting .

Comment: Please provide the actual SQL you are running and the error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

> Tried using try to timestamp , try todate in snowflake but not working it's throwing error converting .

This has come up a few times on the Snowflake tag. You're actually converting it to a formatted string, so you need to use to_varchar instead:

```
select to_varchar('2022-07-04 14:30:00'::timestamp_ltz, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as MY_DATE;
```